# Saving PDF file in SQL Server using Golang

Tags: sql-server, go

I'm having issue in saving a PDF file in SQL Server database using stored procedure in Golang. Below is the code.

```
tsql := fmt.Sprintf("DECLARE @tmp varbinary(max);"+
    "SET @tmp = CAST('%s' as varbinary(max));"+
    "EXEC BP_AddCorrespondenceIn @PatientID=1, @ContactName='Test', @Subject='First Test',"+
    "@Category='Report', @DocType='PDF', @Content = @tmp", content)

// Execute query
rows, err := db().Query(tsql)
```

Here the content is the [ ]byte. When I run the program the query executes and I got the error below:

> mssql: '3�Ze�
> #��!~T��ϔǉQ*���f1-~L���^ը;s;���.�)�[P�hjDN��J�.1��W�Zt���xq�\r���ן�)N���=df' is an invalid name because it contains a NULL character or an invalid unicode character.

Thank you!

Comment: What does `CAST('%s' as varbinary(max))` do? If its a binary file, you shouldn't need to cast it to anything.

Comment: AFAIK go-mssqldb doesn't currently support `varbinary(max)` [parameters](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb#parameter-types). Consider using another library that does, otherwise you're going to have to serialize the PDF content as a varbinary literal (`0x12345678ab...`) and inject it into the SQL statement which is, at best, questionable from a security standpoint. Doing so will also cause cache bloat because there'll be a new plan generated and cached for each call.

Comment: I fixed the problem by changing the stored procedure exec method to 
_, err := db().Exec(tsql, content)
and varbinary(max) conversion to
tmp = CAST(? as varbinary(max));

Thank you for showing me the way to solve the issue guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing the stored procedure exec method to _, err := db().Exec(tsql, content) and varbinary(max) conversion to tmp = CAST(? as varbinary(max));